# True Velocity and Heading

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, mathematical-modeling

An airplane flies at $670$ MPH directly northwest. Wind blows at $70$ MPH from the west (i.e the wind is blowing towards the east). Determine the true velocity and heading of the plane.

Steps:
$<670\cos(3\pi/4), 670 \sin(3\pi/4)>$
$<(-670\sqrt2)/2), (670 \sqrt2)/2)>$
$<70,0>$
$622 \text{ MPH}$
$\arctan(-473.762/403.762)=-49.5^\circ $ rr $180-49.5=131.5^\circ$ North of East.

For this question off of a Multivariable textbook I am reading, here is the question and the answer. The problem is I don't understand anything that occurred for the steps. So if anyone could help me understand where $3\pi/4$, $622$ MPH, and $\arctan$ came from and help me to understand exactly how this problem was computed, that would be great!

Comment: I think you made a typo and carried it through your calculations...shouldn't $\cos(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ be $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$? Same for $\sin$.

Comment: @ZettaSuro Your right, that was a typo. Fixed. $cos(3pi/4)=\sqrt2/2.$

Comment: You need to do the same for $\sin$ in the $y$ component...and where did you get $\langle{70,0}\rangle$?

Comment: Wait, nevermind, I see that's the speed of the wind.

Comment: <70,0> comes from the wind blowing 70 MPH from the west to east.

Comment: Just to get an idea of what your background in this is (so that I can give you a good answer), do you know what degrees and radians are? And do you know how to convert rectangular to polar coordinates?

Comment: Yes, familiar with degrees and radians. Still practicing my polar skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is basically a vector addition. You are given a magnitude V= 670MPH and a bearing (northwest, i.e $\theta$= 135 degrees measured from the horizontal i.e $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ radians measured from the horizontal). Now to convert a magnitude and a bearing to a vector you convert it into it's components:

$$(v_x , v_y)=(V\cos{\theta , V\sin{\theta})}$$

Where $v_x$ is the velocity in the x-direction (west) and $v_y$ is the velocity in the y-direction (north) .

The reason you want to do this is because it is much easier to add vectors together and convert back to a magnitude and bearing than it is to just combine two scalars.

So back to the problem, using trigonometric relations:

$$(v_x , v_y)=(-670\frac{\sqrt2}{2} ,670 \frac{\sqrt2}{2} )$$

Now you are given the wind vector, note since it is blowing directly east it is already in the form of a vector: $(w_x , w_y)=(70,0)$ .

You can add the components of this vector together to give your the resultant velocity vector $(r_x ,r_y)=(v_x , v_y) +(w_x , w_y)=(-670\frac{\sqrt2}{2} +70,670 \frac{\sqrt2}{2} +0)\approx(-403.76 ,473.762)$ .

Now all thats left is to convert this back to a magnitude and bearing. To get the magniude (let's call it R):

$$R=\sqrt{r_x^2+r_y^2}\approx622 MPH$$

and bearing $\phi$ is calculated as:

$$\phi=\arctan{\frac{r_y}{r_x}}\approx-49.5 degrees$$

Comment: But where does 3pi/4 come from? Because it was not given as part of the question. Rather, it was just mentioned in the solution with no explanation.

Comment: Are you familiar with radial measurements? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian

Comment: The use of $3\pi/4$ is somewhat irrelevant in this question, you could calcualate the angles in degrees if you would prefer. Just make sure your calculator is set in the correct mode

Comment: Yes. But still not seeing how 135 was determined.

Comment: The direction the plane moves is northwest. If you measure from the horizontal axis to northwest (which is 45 degrees counterclockwise from 90 degrees) you get exactly 90+45=135

Comment: So when it says North-West, we assume that it is right at between, or 135, if no actual angle is given. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes as the question says the plane flies directly northwest , it is reasonable to assume it means exactly 135 degrees

Comment: Oh, okay. That makes more sense. I was giving myself a headache because I thought I was missing some kind of computation step in order to figure the 135 degrees out.